# How to Iterate on dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a little problem with my code. I would like to create a "for" cycle all over dataframe columns. My solution has a static list, i tried to create a dynamic one putting "df_list_cols= df.shape[1]" but obviusly it cannot iterate on an Int object. Any ideas to create a dynamic solution?

My solution above,
Thank you in advance!

```
df_list = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in df_list_cols:
    do stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Iterating columns

You are close. The way the `in` operator is defined for Pandas dataframes, iterating a `pd.DataFrame` object is *equivalent* to iterating over its columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6]})

for col in df:
    print(col)
# A
# B
# C
```

#### Applying functions to each column

In many cases, you may wish to use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply the same function to each column:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x*2)

print(df)
#    A  B   C
# 0  2  6  10
# 1  4  8  12
```

The equivalent if you have a different function for each column is [`pd.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df = df.transform({'A': lambda x: x*2, 'B': lambda x: x*3, 'C': lambda x: x*4})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html):

`df.columns` gives you a list of the columns of the dataframe.

```
In [222]: df.columns.tolist()
Out[222]: ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [218]: for i in df.columns:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     ## do your stuff
A
B
C
```